# Recursion missing values cant figure out how to fix have a tester

Tags: java, recursion

This function is supposed to take in 2 parameters: `n` the number of ints in an array and `max` which is the max value of an int in the array (the default value is 1). This function returns the number of options possible for the array.

For example when `n` = 3 and `max` = 2

1. ```
   {1, 1, 1}  2. {1, 1, 2} 3. {1, 2, 2} 4. {2, 2, 2}
   ```

and when `max` = 3 and `n` = 2

2. ```
   {1, 1} 2. {1, 2} 3. {1, 3} 4. {2, 2} 5. {2, 3} 6. {3, 3}
   ```

This is my code:

```
public class Ex14 {
    public static int howManySorted(int n, int max) {
        int[] myIntArray = new int[n];
        fillAnArray(myIntArray, 0);
        return howManySorted(myIntArray, max, 0, 1);
    }

    private static int howManySorted(int[] myIntArray, int max, int i, int way) {
        way++;
        myIntArray[i]++;
        if (i < myIntArray.length - 1)
            if (myIntArray[i] == max)
                i++;
        if (myIntArray[myIntArray.length - 1] == max) return way;


        return (howManySorted(myIntArray, max, i, way));
    }

    //filling the array with ones for defualt way when all values equals 1
    private static void fillAnArray(int[] myIntArray, int t) {
        if (t == myIntArray.length)
            return;
        else 
            myIntArray[t] = 1;
        fillAnArray(myIntArray, t + 1);
    }
}
```

My code seems to give me the correct value 4 if using the first example on the second it skips one array.
tester:

```
public class Tester14 {
    public static void main() {
        System.out.println("Test: Checking method 'howManySorted' on n=3 and max=2");
        System.out.println("Expected result = 4, Student result = "
            + Ex14.howManySorted(2, 3) + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to contain the relevant code. Don't post links.

Comment: i tried many times but I was not able to pastebin is not violation of the forums laws..

Comment: What do you mean by  "number of options possible for the array" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting numbers from 1 to chosen number using recursion only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54064604/setting-numbers-from-1-to-chosen-number-using-recursion-only)

Comment: (duplicate) I answered the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54064604/setting-numbers-from-1-to-chosen-number-using-recursion-only

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with your code
you first increment each cell until max value
and then when you reach max you shift to the next cell of the array
that's way for every example that `max > 2` you 
want return values when both cells need to increment
for example in the second test you miss `{2,2}`

your steps are :

- {1,1}
- {2,1}
- {3,1}
- {3,2}
- {3,3}

Comment: you welcome mark it as closed ,  or if you want to try a new solution edit your question

Comment: so how do i fix this then? i have been trying but no solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54064604/setting-numbers-from-1-to-chosen-number-using-recursion-only